# Polymorphic/Metamorphic malware is written on low-level or high-level languages?

Tags: malware

As a part of a course I study polymorphic/metamorphic malware. Every single paper and article I've stumbled upon mentions the *techniques* used by a malware to achieve polymorphism/metamorphism but non is mentioning the language(s) in which most polymorphic/metamorphic is written on or code examples of that particular technique.

My understanding is that malware can be written using almost any language, from Visual Basic, C and C++ to Java and Python. My question is: In order to achieve polymorphic/metamorphic behavior do you need a low level or a high lever language? Do we know which language most polymorphic/metamorphic malwares use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Polymorphic/metamorphic is usually at least partially written in a low level language.**

The purpose of polymorphic malware is to evade virus scanners.  It does so by making it hard to identify a signature for the file.  The simplest version, of course, is a loader which decrypts a section of code when it is time to run.  However, this has a limitation: the loader is now an easy signature to spot!

The solution is to write the loader in a polymorphic manner itself.  This is a sort of chicken and the egg problem.  However, we know the application EVENTUALLY gets compiled down to machine code, so polymorphic code developers will write machine code which can be mixed and mutated and still work.

This low level work is very hard to do in any language above assembly, because the higher level you go, the more of a signature you'll leave behind (high level languages were never written to avoid leaving signatures).

However, that doesn't mean the entire malware has to be low level.  Once you can make a poylmorphic malware that knows how to decrypt and encrypt code, it becomes possible to write the rest of the virus in a high level language, and just attach it to the low level polymorphic loader/encrypter/decrypter.

(And, of course, this battle will continue if the virus scanner looks at memory after decrypting, but I think just handling this "scan the file for signatures" Virus Scanner approach should get you going!)

Comment: So I understand that encryption requires a low level language but encryption is mainly used by polymorphic malware. Metamorphic malware uses techniques such as [Garbage Code Insertion, Register usage exchange, Permutation Techniques etc](http://media.techtarget.com/searchSecurityUK/downloads/RH5_Evgenios.pdf). Do these techniques require low-level languages as well?

Comment: Generally they do require low level languages.  If you think about it, to be polymorphic you either need to a) have source code with you at all times, or b) be polymorphic at the assembly level.  I don't know of many malware that rely on carrying around a copy of the source code to compile with gcc, though they may exist.  Once you start working on the assembly level, though it gets harder.  Compilers are designed to make a lot of automated decisions for you, so its sometimes hard to figure out where to insert garbage, or permute algorithms.  It becomes easier to just do it by hand in assembly

Comment: That all being said, "require" is a very strict word.  I'd say they're much easier with low level languages.  I've seen some astonishingly clever C++ code in my life, so I'd feel rude telling some of those coders they "can't" do polymorphic techniques in C++